# How and when does the program reach "return True"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code (an assignment), this code is correct, however I played around with it and got it on my second try, but I don't know if my understanding is correct:

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: boolean, True if all the letters of secretWord are in lettersGuessed;
      False otherwise
    '''
    # FILL IN YOUR CODE HERE...
    for i in secretWord:
        if i not in lettersGuessed:
            return False
    return True
```

So, if the return True was outside the loop, it would only return True if every single letter in secretWord was in there, but if one letter was missing, it would return False instantly. Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: You say "but if one word was missing, it would return False instantly." When actually it's "but if one **letter** was missing, it would return False instantly." It would be a lot better if `i` was written as `letter` to not trip anyone reading this function... I had to read it over a few times before i understood.

Comment: Yep you’re correct - this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Right -- this is equivalent to:

```
all(lett in lettersguessed for lett in secretword)
```

Note that since membership tests of lists (or strings) are `O(n)`, it can be faster if you have a comparatively larger `secretword` than `lettersguessed` to do:

```
def is_word_guessed(secretword, lettersguessed):
    guessed_set = set(lettersguessed)
    return all(lett in guessed_set for lett in secretword)
```

This is because testing membership in a set is done in constant time (`O(1)`), so the cost of constructing the set is outweighed by the many calls to membership check.

As usual in these sorts of edge optimizations -- profiling is highly recommended before making any change.